# Some key words are required when click Submit

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, regex

I am developing a website. In the website, I am creating a Textarea, which allows users to input the messages. Below the Textarea, there is a Submit button. When users click on the Submit button, the messages which users input will be recorded and displayed in another page.

My question is:

When users input their messages, I want users to include some Key Words (e.g. www.keyword.com, www.keyword.net ..etc.) with their messages. If they do not input those keywords, once they click on Submit button, users will be alert with a message, "Please input some key words that provided." How can I write the code to solve this problem ? Thank You.

Comment: Did you try anything so far ? Doing it using Javascript would be the best solution, PhP is ok otherwise. A quick search for "Check input before submit" would be enough to find a lot of similar questions

Comment: Check for some JS tutorials if you haven't started writing code for that. `Google` it.

Answer (score 2):

Web Form

```
<button type="submit" onclick="check_textArea()">Submit</button>
```

add js below to ur web page

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function check_textArea()
{
    var data = document.getElementById("Your_Text_Area_ID").value;
    if(condition_for_check_your_keywords) //use match() here
    {
        //success msg
        //return true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Please input some key words that provided");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following is the Javascript way which is the simplest (best) way because it validates from the client-side rather than the server..

Form  code:

```
<form action ="some_page.php" onsubmit="return validate()">

<textarea id ="text"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit"/>

</form>
```

Javascript code :

```
function validate()
{

    var words = $('#text').val().replace(/\n/g , " ").split(" ");
    var keywords = new Array();
    keywords = ["www.keyword.com" , "www.keyword.net" ];

    for ( var i = 0 ; i < words.length ; i ++ )
    {
       for ( var j = 0; j < keywords.length; j ++)
       {
           if( words[i] === keywords[j])
           {
               // atleast one keyword ispresent
                  alert("present");
                  return 1;
           }
       }

    }
    alert("Please input some key words that provided");
    return 0;
}
```

However, it would be best if you validate from the server side as well.

Answer (score 1):

you can create a form that contains the textarea and a submit button. The submit button can post to a PHP file to check the strings that you want to check with (your desired keyword to). There will be if-else statement to check.

JavaScript can also be done by creating the function and the form will call this function. If-else statement can be used. Use alert function to prompt user with this message, "Please input some key words that provided."

I agree with C. Malet that JavaScript is the best solution. PHP is needed for server sided. JavaScript client side is fine.

Hope this helps a little on the logic.